# Inverse Function of $ f(x) = \frac{1-x^3}{x^3} $

Tags: functions, inverse

I need to show that these function has a continuous inverse function and find this inverse function.

$$ f(x) = \frac{1-x^3}{x^3} $$

Defined on $ (1,\infty) $

I think I need to check for bijectivity. Don't know how.

I tried to solve the function to $x$ then. But somehow I only end up with $ -\frac{1}{x^3} = -1 -y $ and don't know how to get to $x = ...$

Maybe there is no inverse function!? Or maybe just on the defined area? I don't know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have almost done, but made a small mistake (me too in the first version of the answer): From 
$$y = \frac{1}{x^3}-1$$ 
you get
$$\frac{1}{x^3} = 1+y$$
and therefore
$$x^3 = \frac{1}{1+y}$$
This show that the inverse is for $-1 < y \le 0$
$$f^{-1}(y) = x = \frac{1}{(1+y)^{\frac{1}{3}}}$$
The range restriction for $y$ comes from the fact, that the range of the function is  $-1 < f(x) \le 0$

Comment: Why $ 0 \leq y \lt 1 $? im missing simple math basics here. i'm sorry.

Comment: Because the range of $f$ is $0 \le f(x) < 1$.

Comment: yeah. now i got that. thanks!

Comment: @gammatester you missed the OP function. it seems to be the answer of another question!

Comment: You're right @I'mtoo, I have made the corrections.

Comment: @gammatester: Yes, it's now looks better. thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The original function $f$ takes an $x$ and spits out $y=f(x)$. The inverse is a function $g$ that takes any $y$ from the range of $f$ and spits out $x=g(y)$ such that $g(f(x))=x$ for any $x$ in the domain. So you want to solve for $y$ - you already almost got the correct answer. Once you get $x=g(y)$ for some function $g$, check that $g(f(x)) = x$ to make sure.

Comment: yeah but how do I proceed when on my left hand i have $ \frac{1}{x^3} $ How do I solve this to $ x = $ without multiplying on both sides with $ x^3 $

Comment: @DominiqueLüber: I give you a complete argument.

Answer (score 2):

Let $$y=\frac{1-x^3}{x^3}$$ then $$y=\frac{1}{x^3}-1$$
then we have $$x=\frac{1}{\sqrt[3]{1+y}}$$

Comment: is $ 1/a = b => a = 1/b $ ? Or how do you came up with that?

Comment: absolutely yes! if $y+1=\frac{1}{x^3}$ then $x^3=\frac{1}{y+1}$ and we have the latter equality! (you must implicitly not $a=0$ and not $b=0$)

Comment: of course. to early in the day. I was blind. :) thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So, you know how to get x³ = ..., right? If so, just do the cube root:

$$x = \sqrt[3]{ \frac{1}{1+y} }$$

You can simplify this to become:

$$ x = \frac {1}{\sqrt[3]{1+y}}$$

Comment: Oh well, no points for me :P